# How to preserve django test database after running test cases

Tags: python, django, satchmo

When I run test cases by typing

```
python manage.py test myapp
```

After test cases completed, test databases deleted by default by django test runner. I don't want it to be deleted.

I can use any database!

I want to preserve my database because there are bugs in database that I wanted to see in database that created. So that I can pinpoint them!

Comment: Are you using SQLite?  Can you switch to MySQL?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606756/how-can-i-specify-a-database-for-django-tests-to-use-instead-of-having-it-build-i/4606983

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on the reason why you want to preserve the database? It's always possible this isn't your real problem but for example bad test code is.

Comment: can MySQL solve this problem. so that my test database remains

Answer (score -5, accepted):

According to [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#the-test-database):

> Regardless of whether the tests pass
>   or fail, the test databases
>   are destroyed when all the tests have
>   been executed.

Although, [fixtures](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/?from=olddocs#fixture-loading) might be a help in your situation. Just create initial data, you want to be there when test starts, as texture, and make test load it.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Please update it with new and relevant information.

Answer (score 16):

You can prevent the test databases from being destroyed by using the `test --keepdb` option.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Answer (score 12):

While passing `-k` to `manage.py test` will retain the test database, it will still delete the records that was created in your test cases.  This is because Django's `TestCase` classes will still reset your database after every test case (`django.test.TransactionTestCase` will do a `flush`, while `django.test.TestCase` will wrap each of your test case in a transaction and do a rollback when the test case is done).

The only real solution to making Django retain test data is to extend the `TestCase` class and override the code that resets your database.

*However*, if you do not have the time to do this, you can also make your test case *pause* execution before it finishes, giving you the time to inspect your database before it gets reset.  There are several ways of achieving this, but, now, **THIS IS A HACK**, asking for user `input` in your Python code will make Python pause execution and wait for user input.

```py
from django.test import TestCase


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_something_does_something(self):
        result = do_something_with_the_database()
        self.assertTrue(result)

        # Ask for `input` so execution will pause and wait for input.
        input(
            'Execution is paused and you can now inspect the database.\n'
            'Press return/enter key to continue:')
```

Alternatively, you can also use `pdb`'s `set_trace` function, which will also make the execution pause and wait for input, and at the same time lets you debug the environment in that point of code execution.

Just make sure that you remove the `input()` (or `pdb.set_trace()`) call before you send your code to your automated build system or else it will wait for user input and time out.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-keepdb), you can preserve the database after running tests by:

```
$ python manage.py test -k
```

or

```
$ python manage.py test --keepdb
```

Answer (score 8):

To **preserve whole database** state **after test execution** (not only tables structure)

1. Make sure your test class is based on `django.test.SimpleTestCase` (not TestCase or TransactionTestCase)
2. Take one of your tests for which you want to preserve database state
3. Add the following code to your test class to prevent database tables cleaning after the test execution

```
    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        pass
```

4. Run the test with `--keepdb` parameter, like `./manage.py test app.test --keepdb` - to prevent whole DB cleaning  after test execution
5. Wait for the test to finish
6. Profit! Take snapshot/discover your test_database [do not forget that Django by default will add prefix `test_` to your default database name]

Example of command for test **test_copy**

> ./manage.py test --noinput --keepdb api.tests.SomeTests.test_copy

```
class SomeTests(SimpleTestCase):
    allow_database_queries = True

    def setUp(self):
        super(SomeTests, self).setUp()
        self.huge_set_up_operations()

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.huge_init_database()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        pass

    def test_copy(self):
        SubscriptionFactory()
```

Comment: Another note, you also may need to add `allow_database_queries = True` attribute to the `SomeTests` class if there are any queries.

Comment: Using `allow_database_queries = True` is deprecated since django 2.2 use `databases = "__all__"` instead! see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/64487965/5804947

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in a Pytest environment I use the following pytest.ini for testing

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings.test
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
addopts =
    --ds=myapp.settings.test
    --reuse-db
    --nomigrations
```

note the "--resuse-db" command argument/addpots