# Assertion error while testing Django views

Tags: django, django-views, django-testing, django-tests

**This is my testing function for views.py which I have mention below:**

```
def test_operation_page(self):
    url = reverse('operation')
    response = self.client.get(url)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'abc.html')
    self.assertContains(response, '<b>BOOK id having certain title:</b>')
```

**This is the error I am having while testing my views**

> AssertionError: Database queries to 'default' are not allowed in SimpleTestCase subclasses. Either subclass TestCase or TransactionTestCase to ensure proper test isolation or add 'default' to home.tests.TestViews.databases to silence this failure.

**This is my views.py**

```
def operation(request):
    queryset=Mytable.objects.filter(title="The Diary of Virginia Woolf  Volume Five: 1936-1941").values('bookid')
    textset=list(Mytable.objects.order_by('-bookid').values('title'))
    context={

    'key1' : queryset, 
    'key2' : textset
    }
    return render(request,'abc.html',context)
```

**This is my urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',v.index,name='index'),
path('abc/',v.operation,name='operation')
```

]

Answer (score 12):

It would be something like either you inherit the `TestCase` or `TransactionTestCase` or by using the same `SimpleTestCase` in the following way

```
class CustomClass(django.test.SimpleTestCase):
    databases = '__all__'
    ...
```

Earlier `SimpleTestCase` had dependency on `allow_database_queries = True` which is depreciated since `django` version 2.2.

This attribute is deprecated in favor of `databases`. The previous behavior of `allow_database_queries = True` can be achieved by setting `databases = '__all__'`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.databases

Comment: This worked for me, however, because I was using a read replica, I did need to use TransactionTestCase https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/advanced/#tests-and-multiple-databases

Note: that seems to run quite slowly, so much so that I ultimately ended up going a different route where I made an app config to specify which db I wanted to use per env, including for automated tests

Answer (score 8):

As it states in the docs under [SimpleTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase), "If your tests make any database queries, use subclasses `TransactionTestCase` or `TestCase`."

The error that you are getting is telling you that your view is trying to execute a database query in a subclass of `SimpleTestCase`. You should change what `TestCase` class you are using - that should solve the error.

Comment: is this new? I had tons of tests that ran fine under Django 2.1.5 that now break with this error on 2.2

Comment: That might be related to this change https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.databases

Comment: as suggested there, adding `databases = '__all__'` to the TestCase class instance seems to have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomepageTests(SimpleTestCase):
```

above subclass(SimpleTestCase) change with parent class(TestCase)

```
class HomepageTests(TestCase):
```

use it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Z4CG.png)