# In django unittests how do you specify a database that you are modifying?

Tags: django, database-connection, django-unittest

In django, while testing, how do you resolve the error 'Database connections to {blah} are not allowed in this test. Add {blah class} to ensure proper test isolation and silence this failure'?

Comment: Solution 1: you read the error message and try to understand what it's saying. In this case, it's rather clear, but well, if you don't understand it, solution 2 is usually to do a search on the error message, which usually brings some answers, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007022/assertion-error-while-testing-django-views)

Comment: Sorry the error message was a bad synopsis. "Add 'tracking' to toool.detective.tests.test_views.BulkUPLookupGeneric.databases to ensure proper test isolation and silence this failure. How do I modify the value of databases? I tried updating in setUp with self.databases='tracking' and other attempts which failed to resolve the test. The class is derived from TestCase and I call super().setUp(). Thanks for taking the time to answer

Comment: If the dup _really_ doesn't answer your question, please edit your question with all __relevant__ details (see [ask] and [mcve]) - what your test code, db setup etc looks like, what you've tried and what (links to the doc or similar questions) and for each think you tried how it "failed" _exactly_ (exact error message and traceback), etc.

Comment: Thanks. Found it. I add "databases='__all__'" in the class, and all was fine. I wasn't sure what the collection I was to use if I wanted to specify databases to be multiple datbases. thanks again

Comment: Glad your problem is solved ;-)