# Restart the process where the error has been detected

Tags: python, django, django-testing

In a Django project, it is possible to create unit-tests to verify what we had done so far. The principle is simple. We have to execute the command `python3 manage.py test` in the shell. When an error is detected in the program, the shell will display it and stop the process. However, the procedure has a little gap. If we have several errors, we have to correct it and restart the whole process. This process could take several minutes which depends of our program. Is there a manner to restart the process where the error has been detected instead of restart the whole procedure?

**EDIT :**

In fact, another problem I have is to retain the databases instead of recreate it. How could I do such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to automatically run only failing tests you need to use a third party testing driver like Nose or create your own. But it's not worth it because ...

> You can specify particular tests to run by supplying any number of
>   “test labels” to ./manage.py test. Each test label can be a full
>   Python dotted path to a package, module, TestCase subclass, or test
>   method. For instance:

```
# Run just one test method
$ ./manage.py test animals.tests.AnimalTestCase.test_animals_can_speak
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/overview/

This approach can be used to re run only the ones that have failed.

Please note that third party test runners will probably recreate the database every time you run the test - even for only the failing test. On the other hand the django default test runner has the --keep option which allows the database to be reused. For more details see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37100979/267540

Comment: It is not excellent, because they have to recreate the databases at the beginning.

Comment: That is where the `-k` flag comes into the picture