# How to initialize test database in django?

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I am writing a test cases for my project written in django, it's giving an unexpected output that looks like `{u'message': u'', u'result': {u'username': u'john', u'user_fname': u'', u'user_lname': u'', u'cur_time': 1442808291000.0, u'dofb': None, u'sex': u'M', u'u_email': u'', u'role': u'', u'session_key': u'xxhhxhhhx', u'mobile': None}, u'error': 0}`

Here we can see other field are empty because I just created user in test cases, but not given other info. database is created from the production database, but not initialized, it remains empty. **That's why it is giving other field empty.** It is querying empty database.

I have written following test case for **login REST API**. and running it by **python manage.py test**. Please tell me how to solve above problem.

***Note: If following approach is not correct then you can suggest other approach.***

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import json

class TestAPI(TestCase):

      def setUp(self):
            self.c=Client() #Create Client object that simulates request to a url similar to a browser can
            User.objects.create_user(username="john", password="xxx")

      def test_login_api(self):
            credential_test=dict()
            c_test =Client()

            credential_test["username"]="john"
            credential_test["password"]="xxx"
            data=json.dumps(credential_test)
            #print 'data is'
            #print data
            response_test =c_test.put('/api/login', data)
            content_test=json.loads(response_test.content)
            print 'content'
```

Comment: Django test client expects a dictionary as postdata, not a json dump of a dictionary.  And why are you authenticating with PUT instead of POST? put i usually for file uploads

Answer (score 1):

Try change it :

```
User.objects.create(username="john", password="xxx")
```

to:

```
User.objects.create_user(username='john', password='xxx')
```

The method `create_user` use `set_password` method.

```
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    # ...   
    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email = UserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email,
                          is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_superuser=False,
                          last_login=now, date_joined=now)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Comment: thanks its working, but in response other details are empty, like user_first name and user_last name, Thats why I am trying to initialize with production database..

Comment: how are u trying to catch they, and where?

Comment: this user table is related with other tables so for this it will empty, that why i want to initialize test database with production database.

Comment: I think this can help u, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646468/how-to-run-django-unit-tests-on-production-database

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches:

1. Expand your use of setUp() to create records for the other models and establish a valid set of relationships between the models you create. It's the configuration-via-code approach.
2. Use fixtures to prepopulate your test dbs. If you do some research you can find out how to create some fixtures using an existing, valid db. However I would advise you to sanitize any production data that you use for testing. Aka a configuration-via-data approach.

Comment: I current approach testing is very slow So I want to use sqlite3 for speed-up So please tell me how to initialize sqlite3 with production database...

Comment: @geeks that sounds like a different question. The answer for this question is pretty good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606756/how-can-i-specify-a-database-for-django-tests-to-use-instead-of-having-it-build