# Run Django unit tests from custom management command

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I used to have a standalone script with some unit tests to test data in our database. I did not use the builtin Django testing tool, as that would create an empty testing database, which is not what I want.

In that script, I created three different classes extending `unittest.TestCase` containing some test functions that directly executed SQL statements.

Now I would prefer to be able to access the Django ORM directly. The easiest way to do this is via a custom management commant (`./manage.py datatests`).

In the standalone script, I could call all unit tests via the following function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It would discover all tests in the current file and run them.

How can I do an equivalent thing (run some test suites) from within a custom Django management command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry for not having searched for an answer long enough before asking, but I found the solution to this problem myself in another Stackoverflow answer:

- [How to run django unit-tests on production database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646468/how-to-run-django-unit-tests-on-production-database/1648881#1648881)

Essentially, instead of `unittest.main()` the following code can be used:

```
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestCaseClass)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

This will load all tests in the specified TestCaseClass. If you want to load all tests in the current module, creating the suite this way will help:

```
suite = TestLoader().loadTestsFromName(__name__)
```

The Stackoverflow answer linked above contains a full example. Furthermore, the *Basic Example* section of the [unittest module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#basic-example) describes the same thing. For other options to load tests, see *Loading and running tests* in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#loading-and-running-tests).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to specify the contents of your start-up db through `fixtures`. It will load up the context for db for particular test. And you can take a snapshot of db with

```
$ ./manage.py dumpdata my_app > fixtures/my_pre_test_db.json`
```

Now in your unit test you will have something like this:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['fixtures/my_pre_test_db.json']

    def testThisFeature(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. But in my case that won't be a solution, as our database consists of millions of rows. Populating the database would take several minutes if not hours.