# Persistence with Django Test Runner

Tags: django, unit-testing, integration-testing

I'm writing tests for a mildly complex Django based infrastructure application where data in one Django project is dependent on data in another Django project.

I'm using vagrant and have both projects communicating with one another in a test environement and have written a test for a "create" view on Project1.

The database of Project2 is affected (expected behavior) upon running the test in Project1.  I then go to run the tests in Project2 which should affect the data just created in Project1, but it appears (after checking in the admin of Project1) that the data created in Project1 in the initial tests is not persistent, causing the test in Project2 to fail.

I've moved the test to a management command, as described in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1648881/1419446, but would really like to use Django.test.TestCase as opposed to the TestCase provided by unittest.

Is there anyway to prevent the rolling back of changes made to the database during a test?